# Localhost server is not running in my next js project after running 'npm run dev' command. This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, localhost

I try to install the next js in my pc and followed this following documentation to setup next js project.
https://nextjs.org/docs

steps i followed

1. npx create-next-app@latest
2. asking me name of my project
3. do want to use typescript ? selected no
4. do want to use eslint ? selected no
5. do want to use tailwind css ? selected no
6. do want to use '/src' typescript ? selected no

after it got installed and started my server with command
'npm run dev'

its start the server but , server gets stopped automatically after 3 seconds

this my folder structure
[image]

this is my .next file
[image]

my package.json file image
[image]

this is my command log
[image]

can anyone help me solve this error it will be big help pls thank you !!!

Comment: Can you share the log after the server stops, also your package.json file?

Comment: yes just a min i will edit question

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47670

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is that i had node version x32 in my computer. so i have to uninstall and install latest stable node version and after that its started the next js server.

to check the node version just typed the following command.
**node -p process.arch**

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by updating my Node.js version to match my Next.js version. Since my Next.js version is 14, I updated Node.js to version 20.5.1. This ensured compatibility and resolved the problem smoothly.